# How can i use condition orders in a simpler way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda

My code looks like this :

```py
Lst = [1 , 11 , 5 , 25, 100]
List(map(lambda x:'small' if x < 10 else : 'big' , lst ))
```

Output will be like :

```
['small' , 'big' , 'small' , 'big' , 'big']
```

My problem is if i use another condition with elif i will get **syntax error** !

```py
List(map(lambda x:'small' if x < 10 x:'average' elif x>10 and x<50 else : 'big', lst ))
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: there is no `elif` for the `if`/`else` ternary operator, that is why you get a syntax error. To obtain a behavior similar to `elif` you have to chain multiple `if`/`else` ternary operators.

Comment: Idk why people vote down without telling their reasons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `if` clause as the else block

```
>>> lst = [1 , 11 , 5 , 25, 100]
>>> list(map(lambda x: 'small' if x < 10 else ('average' if x>10 and x<50 else 'big'), lst ))
['small', 'average', 'small', 'average', 'big']
```

The parenthesis around the else block is optional and is included just for readability